# Service is crashing on galaxy nexus but not the emulator

Tags: android, service

I got a strange problem with service. It works correctly and flawlessly on ICS emulator. But when I launch it on Galaxy Nexus with ICS 4.0.4 I observe strange crashing of the service without any stacktraces. Below is all what I got:

```
07-11 16:26:37.758: INFO/ActivityManager(136): Process com.test.service (pid 3899) has died.
07-11 16:26:37.758: WARN/ActivityManager(136): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.test.service/.MyService in 20000ms
```

I have googled but found no idea. May be it is somehow connected with memory pressure? What am I expected to do?

**UPD**

P.S. If it makes any sense I launch a background thread from onStartCommand() and this thread works infinitely.

P.P.S. I tried to launch service in separate process with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that, the System occasionally removes/kills processes that it deems unnecessary at the time. If, however, `onStartCommand` returns `START_STICKY`, it will be restarted as soon as it's killed... I fail to see the point of killing such processes, though I guess it can help in under extreme situations. The Emulator behaviour might vary.

Assuming that your service doesn't ***actually crash*** (there should be some kind of stack trace in the logcat), to prevent the system from killing the service so easily, it must be started as a [foreground](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29) service.

Comment: startForeground seems to look helpful. I will give it a try, thank you.